# Weird TextArea behavior in IE

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I have been working on a site that includes a textarea for comments to be inserted by the user and everything looks great on the details page on submission on all browsers, except IE. I get the following issue as presented in the screenshot below:
[image: Weird TextArea Image]

Any clues on how to fix this issue? I am using bootstrap with some custom css styles, but not a lot really affects the textarea. It seems like a new line is being inserted or IE thinks the textarea is smaller than it should be. Here is the code for the textarea:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, 5, 50, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
        </div>
 </div>
```

Everything else looks fine and there are other textareas on the screen that do not have this issue. Here is a screenshot of a textarea with no issue on the same page:
[image: Fine TextArea]

With the code for it presented below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Complaint.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Complaint.Comments, 5, 50, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Provided below:

```css
/*! CSS Used
textarea{margin:0;font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
@media print{
*{color:#000!important;text-shadow:none!important;background:transparent!important;box-shadow:none!important;}
}
*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;}
textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit;}
textarea{background-image:none;}
.form-control:-moz-placeholder{color:#999999;}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder{color:#999999;}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#999999;}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#999999;}
.form-control{display:block;width:100%;height:34px;padding:6px 12px;font-size:14px;line-height:1.428571429;color:#555555;vertical-align:middle;background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #cccccc;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);-webkit-transition:border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;transition:border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;}
.form-control:focus{border-color:#66afe9;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);}
.form-control[readonly]{cursor:not-allowed;background-color:#eeeeee;}
textarea.form-control{height:auto;}
textarea{max-width:280px;}
```

Thanks for any assistance provided for this interesting problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? The main difference of your two examples layout-wise is the **column width** you specify for both your **label** and your **text area**. See also: [Bootstrap grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

Comment: Basically I want the textarea to wrap the text like the second example instead of way too soon. I am not sure why this is happening and the label & column widths are the only notable differences i can find as well. I have changed the class with different widths and no change seems to have any effect on how the textarea wraps.

Comment: Show us your CSS.

Comment: It would be great if you could put together a [mcve] of the rendered HTML and CSS. You might also want to describe the issue in words rather than just an image, so that search engines will find the question.

Comment: Have you checked your displayed text, that it doesn't contain any Newline characters? (Newline characters are displayed literally in textareas).

Comment: Heretic Monkey I will work on getting that. It could get rather large though.

Comment: Hey Poul Bak, I have, the textarea displays properly on other browsers.

Comment: @PoulBak CSS has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue, at one point of time the table had a char(100) type for the comments field meaning it padded XX number of characters. Apparently, IE and several other text editors have a limit on how many characters per line and thus it was breaking the content up into two lines. Once the EF had been updated to no longer have a fixed length for that field and all trailing spaces removed this worked perfectly.

Very strange issue, but thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the first code example, try changing `<div class="col-md-10">` to `<div class="col-md-9">`. I observed that this is the difference in the parent `<div>` of the textbox in each example.

Comment: No change, it seems that the div class has no impact on the textarea's text wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Complaint.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true, @rows = 5, @cols = 50 })
```

Comment: [answer] mentions "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Generally, answers which explain the code are upvoted more than those which do not.

Comment: Not really sure what the purpose of moving the rows and columns into the htmlAttributes when the Helper offers these values in the declaration, but this change had no impact.

Comment: @rientelfon could you inspect that textarea element and give us the css that is applied to it?

Comment: @WahidMasud this has been added.

Comment: @rientelfon Well I've tried it myself specifically for IE  and it works. Maybe there is something else that's causing the problem. maybe an unintentional new line or something else. If you could create this same problem in somewhere like jsfiddle then everyone could actually try to solve it. because honestly i cant see any problems. so good luck.

Comment: @WahidMasud Yeah, I have also replicated this view in a fresh project and do not experience the issue in IE. I am definitely at a loss here. However, on any PC I use with the original view it gives me the problem.